# Fontawasome vertical icon align

Tags: html, css

Why `vertical-align: middle;` does not align icons to middle of a header?

```css
    .custom {
        color: white;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background: rgb(40,40,40);
    }
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="header">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook custom" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-twitter custom" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-instagram custom" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-google-plus custom" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these days, the best way to align to center vertically is to use flexbox. See also:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

```css
.custom {
        color: white;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

.header {
  
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;

        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background: rgb(40,40,40);
    }
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="header">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook custom" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-twitter custom" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-instagram custom" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-google-plus custom" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.custom {
    color: white;
    vertical-align: middle;
    **line-height: 40px;**
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give some margin to `.custom` `margin-top=2.5%` or `margin=2.5%` and it'll work.

On the other hand, `vertical-align` would also work if you had something like this;

```
<a class="header">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook custom" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why its not working is because you have mentioned height remove height and it will   be aligned to middle, instead of height use padding for the parent class , for you its header .

```
.custom {
    color: white;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    padding:20px;
    background: rgb(40,40,40);
}
```